# Order of a Homogeneous Function

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

let $f(x,y)$ be a homogeneous function of order 2. What is the order of 
$-x\cdot (f(x,y))^{2}$?

More generally:

> **Q.** How do you determine the order of the product of two homogeneous functions, and what happens when you multiply a homogeneous function by a variable such as $x$?

Comment: $x$ is homogeneous of order one, so...

Comment: Try an example if you don't believe it.

Comment: Oh, x is homogeneous itself, I didn't think of it. So simple. And what about the product ? Is there a rule, or do I have to use the definition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x, y)=xy$, so that $f(tx,ty)=tx\cdot ty=t^2xy=t^2f(x,y).$

Now consider $g(x,y)=-x(f(x,y))^2=-x(xy)^2.$
$$g(tx,ty)=-tx(f(tx,ty))^2=-tx\cdot (tx\cdot ty)^2=t^5(-x(xy)^2)=t^5g(x,y).$$

So, the degree of homogenity is $5$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $g (x,y)=-x (f (x,y))^2$.

then

$$g (\lambda x,\lambda y)=$$
$$-\lambda x (f (\lambda x,\lambda y))^2=$$
$$-\lambda x (\lambda^2f (x,y))^2=$$
$$\lambda^5 g (x,y). $$

thus the order is $5$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f_i$ is homogeneous of degree $d_i$, the product $f_1f_2\cdots f_k$ is homogeneous of degree $d_1+d_2+ \cdots +d_k$ (easy induction on the number of factors).

In your case, there are three factors $x$, $f$, $f$ of respective degree $1$, $2$, $2$, so the degree of the product is $1+2+2=5.$

Comment: shouldn't the d's be with + rather than * ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Corrected, thanks